# System.Data.OracleClient on Windows 7 64

Tags: visual-studio, oracle, windows-7

I'm trying to access an Oracle Database from a program I'm writing on Windows 7 64bit. Whenever it initializes the client, i get a `BadImageFormatException` complaining that I'm trying to use a 32bit client in a 64bit environment. I've tried to compile the program in any way (Any CPU, 32, 64 bit), but it did not solve the problem. Any help?

Comment: Are you referencing the 64 bit version of OCI?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the error message is correct. You have a 32 bit Oracle DLL that you use from a 64 process. The Oracle DLL probably does some interop's with native code, that may require it to be processor specific.

There are several ways to solve this.

Option 1: **Get the [64 bit Oracle DLLs.](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/64-bit/index.html)**

Option 2: **Make sure that your process is 32 bit.**
.NET exe files marked for AnyCPU will start a 64 bit process on a 64 bit operating system. But if you mark your EXE file for x86 then it should work. For Web applications you have to set a 32 bit flag somewhere in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your Project to target the .NET 4 Framework, by going to `Project-Designer` -> `Target Framework`.

Then you need to delete the old `Oracle dll`, and use the new **64-Bit-Version** of the `Oracle dll` that is included in the .NET 4 Framework.